# Wrong Uniswap v2 trade calculation

Tags: uniswap

I'm experimenting with Uniswap v2 WETH/USDC pair in the Rinkeby network and can't understand how swap amounts are calculated.
I can swap 0.1WETH for 17,528,500,000USDC, but at same time 0.001WETH only for 3.75643USDC. How these miscalculations happens on the blockchain?
[image]

[image]

It's not UI bug, I tried to execute these transactions and result was the same:

for [0.1 WETH I got 18,296,951,159.806652USDC](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xc22753576c548456d00bf03aeb0b8dd594a630afee8b182ae014783d529d6f9d);

for [0.0001 WETH I got 0.376021USDC](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x6730d22c77f8588cce504ed9ae3f2a7abc65de6263134cee866446975e3a9c71)

WETH rinkeby address: [0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xc778417e063141139fce010982780140aa0cd5ab)

USDC rinkeby address: [0xeb8f08a975ab53e34d8a0330e0d34de942c95926](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xeb8f08a975ab53e34d8a0330e0d34de942c95926)

WETH/USDC pair uniswap v2 rinkeby address: [0xB1bC33810F9e6E8D417925236991Fcc5012AaaE8](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xB1bC33810F9e6E8D417925236991Fcc5012AaaE8)

**UPDATE**: I analyzed my previous two transactions and looks like I interacted with different smart contracts even though I used the same UI:

Got 18 billions USDC from 0xb1bc33810f9e6e8d417925236991fcc5012aaae8

Got 0.37 USDC from 0x0900a1c7ed3d46b2acdd1916314f63e6288cd718

Why does Uniswap switched between contracts if the same tokens are traded

Comment: The pool 0x0900a1c7eD3D46b2ACdD1916314f63E6288cD718 is created by Uniswap v3 factory, pretty sure it's not a uniswap v2 pool.

Comment: The real problem could be that the UI is not transparent at all, and it giving the user a worse trade in some situations! I hope this does not happen on the mainnet.